# corr2 in matlab returns NaN

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

I am trying to use corr2 for template matching. But when i give the window around first pixel and template matrix to the function, I get NaN error.

```
For ex :- 
template = uint8([1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 0;1 1 1 0]); 
window = uint8([0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0]); 
When i do corr2 on this two matrix :-
r = corr2(template,window);
r = NaN.
```

But if i change one of the zero value in matrix to 1 in window, it give me output other than NaN.
I am following the link :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-OzmDen4HU
for template matching which show output as 0 for the first pixel. I am not getting where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[Corr2 Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html;jsessionid=399145d02bb214153c361908f7ff)

If you look at the bottom of the page under algorithm, it gives the equation who's result will be represented by Corr2.

Your second matrix is a 0 matrix, and as such the second summation in the equation's denominator will be 0, and you will divide by 0.

Comment: so whats the ideal way to do this ? As in the video link, zeros are being shown instead of NaN.I am new to Matlab so i am finding it bit difficult to handle such a case.

Comment: If you check to see if  'nnz(template) == 0' or 'nnz(window) == 0' prior to calculation, then you will know the result will be zero regardless and make that the output.